# problems regarding for and if-else expression in c programming

Tags: c

whenever I'm trying to run a program the only output I get is from the expression else, the statement under if got ignored even if the condition matched. What are my mistakes?`
Heres the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
    int a,b,c=0,d,e,f,g,s=0,h,i;
    printf("Enter the lower limit a\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the upper limit b\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    for(e=a;e<=b;e++)
    {
       f=e;
       do{
       f=f/10;
       c++;
       }while(f!=0);

       g=e;
       do{
       d=g%10;
       s=s+pow(d,c);
       g=g/10;
       }while(g!=0);

       if(s==e){
          h=s;
          printf("\nThe number %d is an armstrong number\n",h);
       }
       else{
          i=e;
          printf("\nThe number %d is not an armstrong number\n",i);
       }
    }   
}
```

Comment: compiling it on ubuntu using gcc

Comment: You need reset some variables each loop.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? If you haven't learned to use one yet, now is the absolutely perfect time to do so. There's no more valuable skill to possess as a developer than how to use a debugger to trace the flow of a program and examine values of variables. (You should also learn now to use better variable names and white space. Reading code that's full of stuff like `s=s+pow(d,c);` buried in a lot of other `a=z;y=r++;if(a==r-z*x){}` is extremely difficult. Code like that in my shop would lead to a coder needing to find a new job.)

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It is better not to use `pow` for such calculations.

Answer (score 0):

As BLUEPIXY said, you need to reset two of your variables each time in your main loop. Also, as Ken White noted your variable naming choices are almost unreadable.

Here is your fixed program with more sensible variable naming choice (that can be made even more sensible if you follow the details of your algorithm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int lim_low, lim_up, count=0, n_mod, num, n1, n2, n_pow=0, res_1, res_2;
    printf("Enter the lower limit\n");
    scanf("%d",&lim_low);
    printf("Enter the upper limit\n");
    scanf("%d",&lim_up);

    for(num = lim_low; num <= lim_up; num++)
    {
        n1 = num;
        count = 0;
        do{
            n1 = n1/10;
            count++;
        }while(n1!=0);

        n2 = num;
        n_pow = 0;
        do{
            n_mod = n2%10;
            n_pow = n_pow+pow(n_mod,count);
            n2 = n2/10;
        }while(n2!=0);

        if(n_pow == num){
            res_1 = n_pow;
            printf("\nThe number %d is an armstrong number\n", res_1);
        }
        else{
            res_2 = num;
            printf("\nThe number %d is not an armstrong number\n",res_2);
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Adding comments to various stages of your code is also good for readability. Finally, as far as I know, `main()` should return `int` rather than `void` although it is not an error. `return 0;` at the end of your `main()` is also not necessary but recommended to signal your operating system that the program terminated without errors.